# Function address in ARM assembly have one byte offset?

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

For example, I have the following assembly code got by `objdump`. The address of `f()` is `080001d4`. But `printf("%x", f)` outputs `080001d5`. And `f()` can be done by `(*((int (*)())080001d5))()` but `(*((int (*)())080001d4))()`.

Why there is one byte offset in function address?

```
080001d4 <f>:
 80001d4:   2000        movs    r0, #0
 80001d6:   4770        bx  lr
```

Comment: The LSB is used to select thumb mode.

Comment: LSB is one bit. But the offset is one byte.

Comment: One bit of the address means one byte.

Comment: Oh I know what you mean. Thanks !

Comment: see the arm documentation on the bx instruction.  the lsbit is removed when the address is latched into the pc, but is required for the bx or pop to work right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ARM has two instruction modes, and the least-significant bit of the address is used to indicate which mode a given function uses.  Odd addresses for Thumb mode, and even addresses for ARM mode.

The address will be even if you recompile it using the `-marm` switch.

Section A4.1.1 "Changing between Thumb state and ARM state" in [1] states the following:

> A processor in Thumb state can enter ARM state by executing any of the 
>   following instructions: BX , BLX , or an LDR
>   or LDM that loads the PC.
>
> ....
>
> The target instruction set is either encoded directly in the instruction
>   (for the immediate offset version of BLX ), or is
>   held as bit[0] of an interworking address.

---

[1] *ARM® Architecture Reference Manual: ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition*. ARM, 2014. DDI 0406C.c. [Online]. Available: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html.  [Accessed 26 Aug. 2019].